# jQueryUI Tooltip + JSON problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

Good Day,

I'm having problems implementing jQueryUI Tooltip.

Here's my code:

```
$("input.tooltip").tooltip({ 
    content: function(response) {
        $.getJSON('tooltipcontent.json', function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) { return item.foo; } ))
        });
                    return 'tooltip content';
    }
});
```

What I'm going to do? I'm going to create json document with text for all input's tooltips. I'm stuck cause tooltip is...empty.

Any ideas?

Tom.

Comment: If you alert `data` what do you get?

Comment: Hi Nick! If I `alert(item.foo);` it displays what it should. Have no idea.

Comment: @Tom - What does `$.each(data, function(item) { response(item.foo); } );` result in?

Comment: @Nick - When I alert, it returns "undefined".

Comment: @Nick - I edited my question, when I put`return 'tooltip content';` tooltip works. Weird.

Comment: @Tom - Which version of jQuery UI are you using?  1.9m1, m2?  Directly returning data follows a different code path than the ajax version, which expect to call `show(e, t, response)`, response being the content

Comment: jQuery UI? 1.8.4. I just downloaded tooltip js and css files ;-)

Comment: So to be clear, `$.each(data, function(item) { response(item.foo); } );` didn't show a tooltip? but doing `alert()` instead of `response()` there does alert the correct text?

Comment: IF I'm not wrong...then yes. Sorry, it's quite late here and I'm sitting with this for over two hours...

Comment: @Tom - Try it real quick...the `$.each(data, function(item) { response(item.foo); } );` *should* be working if the alert of `alert(item.foo)` is the tooltip you want.

Comment: I see, maybe I was placing it in wrong place? Where should I?

Comment: @Tom - Like this overall: `$.getJSON('tooltipcontent.json', function(data) { $.each(data, function(item) { response(item.foo); } ); });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a 'title' attribute to the element you are trying to apply the tooltip to http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tooltips-require-a-title-tag